# can I use one submit button to perform more than one operation?

Tags: javascript, function

[here the console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PkAo.jpg)
can i use the Calculate button to get the Calculation for all the output above ?
here is the code i did but when i click Calculate none of the output appears i know there are a lot of mistakes on the code but i was trying to do it if anyone can tell my what i was doing wrong ?
NOTE : the code is long i had other parts which work as expected but the part i shared below is the problem

```
<body>
<label for="formulas">Choose a formula:</label>
<select name="formulas" id="formulas">
<option value="free">Pipeline Thickness</option>
</select>

<table style="width:100%">
<h2>Enter inputs</h2>

<tr>
<td><label for="P">MAOP(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="P"></td>
<td><label for="SMT">Standerd Manufacturing Thickness (in)=</label>
<input type="number"  id="SMT" value="0.000" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
<td><label for="MOE">E(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="MOE"></td> <!-- Modulus of Elasticity -->
<td><label for="HS">Hoop Stress(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="HS" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="D">D&#8320;(in)=</label>
<input type="number" id="D" onchange="myFunction(this.value)"></td> <!-- Nominal Outside Diameter -->
<td><label for="val">Buckling Check=</label>
<input type="text" id="val" readonly></td>
<td><label for="LCTE">a=</label>
<input type="number" id="LCTE"></td> <!-- Linear Coefficient of Thermal Expansion -->
<td><label for="HSC">Hoop Stress Check=</label>
<input type="number" id="HSC" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="SMYS">SMYS(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="SMYS"></td> <!-- Specified Minimum Yield Streneth -->
<td></td>
<td><label for="TDI">Ti(&deg;F)=</label>
<input type="number" id="TDI"></td> <!-- Temperature During Installation -->
<td><label for="LST">&#x006F;T(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="LST" readonly></td> <!-- Longitudinal Stress due to AT -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="DF">DF=</label>
<input type="number" id="DF"></td> <!-- Design Factor -->
<td></td>
<td><label for="MOT">T&#8338;(&deg;F)=</label>
<input type="number" id="MOT"></td> <!-- Maximum Operating Temperature -->
<td><label for="LSP">&#x006F;P(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="LSP" readonly></td> <!-- Longitudinal Stress due to Internal P -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="T">T=</label>
<input type="number" id="T"></td> <!-- Temperature Derating Factor -->
<td></td>
<td><label for="PR">u=</label>
<input type="number" id="PR"></td> <!-- Poison Ratio -->
<td><label for="LSB">&#x006F;B(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="LSB" readonly></td> <!-- Longitudinal Stress due to Bending -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="E">E &#8521;=</label>
<input type="number" id="E"></td> <!-- Joint Factor -->
<td></td>
<td><button type="button" id="calculate2">calculate</button></td>
<td><label for="NLS">&#x006F;L(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="NLS" readonly></td> <!-- Net Longitudinal Stress -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td><button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><label for="CS">&#x006F;C(psi)=</label>
<input type="number" id="CS" readonly></td> <!-- Combined Stress -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="total">Wall Thickness(in)=</label>
<input type="number" id="total" readonly></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><button type="button" id="Check">Calculate</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
document.getElementById('Check').addEventListener('click'), function() {

var MOE = +document.getElementById("MOE").value;

var LCTE= +document.getElementById("LCTE").value;

var HSC= +document.getElementById("HSC").value;
    
var TDI = +document.getElementById("TDI").value;
    
var MOT = +document.getElementById("MOT").value;
    
var LST = +document.getElementById("LST").value;
    
var LSP = +document.getElementById("LSP").value;
    
var PR = +document.getElementById("PR").value;
  
var LSB= +document.getElementById("LSB").value;

var NLS= +document.getElementById("NLS").value;

var CS= +document.getElementById("CS").value;

var HS= +document.getElementById("HS").value;

var total= document.getElementById("total").value;

var HS= (document.getElementById("P").value * document.getElementById("D").value) / ( 2 * document.getElementById("total").value);

document.getElementById("HS").value = HS;

var HSC= (document.getElementById("DF").value * document.getElementById("SMYS").value);
document.getElementById("HSC").value = HSC;
if (document.getElementById("DF").value * document.getElementById("SMYS").value < document.getElementById("HS").value) {
  document.getElementById("Check").value =("Pass");
}
else {
document.getElementById("Check").value =("Fail");
}

var LST=(document.getElementById("E").value * document.getElementById("LCTE").value (document.getElementById("TDI").value - document.getElementById("MOT").value ));
document.getElementById("LST").value=LST;
};
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you post the HTML code? and Press the "F12" button on your browser, click on the console tab to check if any message is shown.

Comment: @The KNVB
I edit the post with the HTML code and console tab

Comment: Typo.  You have `addEventListener('click'), function()...`, but the function needs to BE the second parameter.  `addEventListener('click', function()...`.

Comment: Besides that, after the last `}` you need to add a `)`, and the `myFunction` is missing.